# Wordpress: Ошибка 404 при пагинации на странице архивов произвольного типа записей

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте. Сделал произвольный тип записей (files), создал под него отдельный файл архива (archive-files.php). Пагинация появляется, но при переходе 404 ошибка.
Вывожу записи в файле архива так:

```
<div id="content" class="content" role="main">

<?php if( have_posts() ){  $args = array('post_type' => 'files', 'posts_per_archive_page' => 2); query_posts( $args );?>
    <ul class="files-list">
    <?php while( have_posts() ){ the_post(); ?>
        <li>
          Тут вывод произвольных полей и верстка.
        </li>
    <?php }  /* конец while */ ?>
    </ul>

    <div class="navigation">
        <?php the_posts_pagination(); ?>
    </div>

<?php
    wp_reset_query(); } // конец if
else
echo "<h4>Записей нет.</h4>"; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убрал query_posts().
Изменения в запрос стал делать через pre_get_posts
Пагинация восстановилась.